# Unable to install igraph on python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, igraph, python-3.7

I need to install python-igraph into python 3.7 through pip3.
When I run: `pip3 install python-igraph`, I get this message error:

> Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-whiv93xm/python-igraph/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-kbqa7cno-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-whiv93xm/python-igraph/

For information, i had it on python 2.7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to install some dependencies before installing the library.
Try this:

```
sudo apt install libxml2-dev libz-dev python-dev python3-dev build-essential
```

Then proceed with:

```
sudo pip3 install python-igraph
```

I hope this works